# Configuring Bazaar in Hudson

Tags: configuration, hudson, bazaar

I am trying to configure a task in Hudson for a VC++ project. I was able to build a project from the file system with MSBuild task. But when I try to configure the task to check out a bazaar repo to do the build, checkout is always failing in authentication. Bazaar passwordless access is setup on the machine and when I use bzr cmd line, checkout is happening without password. Another post suggested that I should have the id_rsa in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.hudson - but that also did not help. In Subversion config I saw a way of mentioning username and password. Is there any way to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The authentication.conf is not being considered in windows. I made the repo accessible through http and configured the bazaar with that URL. It was able to download the repo with http protocol without asking for password. One more thing I did was I created a username in hudson, which I matched with a user having access in the bazaar repo which solved another problem which was asking for a user named pwd.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have set up the authentication in the windows equivalent of ~/.bazaar/authentication.conf (use `bzr version -v` to get the correct location).

Is hudson running as the same user as the one you use to connect with the command-line? Because that will impact which authentication.conf it will try to use.

My hudson is using authentication.conf fine but I run it on Ubuntu.